# 404 for js files when using spring boot with vaadin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

I have a problem when using spring security in a vaadin project with spring-boot. So I'am using a PdfViewer Addon to display PDF Files. But I'm getting the following error message:

```
error:"Not Found"
message:"No message available"
path:"/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js"
status:404
```

and my spring security configuration looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers()
                .defaultsDisabled()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()
                .csrf().disable() // Use Vaadin's CSRF protection
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/APP/PUBLISHED/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("login?debug").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/#!pwdreset/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/pwdreset/*").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/#!login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/#!login?logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession();

    }

@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/VAADIN/**");
    }
```

So checking the loaded files in Chrome I see a folder **/vaadinServlet/APP/PUBLISHED/** and there are all the files needed.

Using the Addon without Spring Security works fine, so anyone any idea?

---

**Update**

It doesn't seem to be related to spring security, because I get a similar behavior while testing the Addon in a new simple project. It seems to be a problem with spring boot.

To reproduce this issue you need ([full project for download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycwGuCn_2LUbERDUWlhYnczMUU/view?usp=sharing)):

- basic spring boot + vaadin app skeleton
- simple PDF and under `/webapp/files`
- [PdfViewer add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/pdfviewer) in your pom and widgetset compiled
- the below simple UI

```java
@Theme("mytheme")
@SpringUI
@Widgetset("org.test.AppWidgetSet")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        String basepath = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File file = new File(basepath.concat("/files/test.pdf"));
        if (file.exists()) {
            PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer(file);
            Label info = new Label("File was found!");
            layout.addComponents(info, pdfViewer);
        } else {
            Label info = new Label("no file found!");
            layout.addComponent(info);
        }
        setContent(layout);
    }
}
```

- open chrome & developer tools with the `Network` tab selected, access the app and you should see one request for `pdf.worker.js` fail.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce your problem? Nothing fancy, just a minimum pom, UI, spring-boot config and launcher (main class) that produces this error. I don't see anything wrong with your config, perhaps you could move all the static resources paths to the `ignore` matcher list in the `configure` method, but it should not be an issue anyway.  I have a similar setup but mine is working fine, so without reproducing it it'd be difficult to understand (for me at least)

Comment: @Morfic I just updated my question because it seems to be a problem with spring boot and it has nothing to do with spring security. While creating an example I get the same error like in my project. May be you have any idea about how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR;** version:

A second request is being triggered by `pdf.js` to download `pdf.worker.js`, but it does not match the path `/vaadinServlet/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js` handled by the auto-configured `VaadinServlet`, it's just `/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js`.

The simplest solution I could come up with, is a controller which [forwards](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) the request to the `VaadinServlet`:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class PdfJsRedirectController {
    private static final String WORKER_JS_INCORRECT_PATH = "/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js";
    private static final String WORKER_JS_CORRECT_FORWARD_PATH = "forward:/vaadinServlet/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js";

    @RequestMapping(value = WORKER_JS_INCORRECT_PATH)
    public String forwardWorkerJsRequestToVaadin() {
        return WORKER_JS_CORRECT_FORWARD_PATH;
    }
}
```

---

**Detailed** version:

So, I've spent some time debugging this, and it turns out to be a combination of unfortunate configs:

- spring dispatcher servlet listening
- vaadin spring servlet listening
- a pdf.js bugfix/woraround

What happens is, spring registers a `DispatcherServlet` serving requests for `/*`. and Vaadin registers a `VaadinSpringServlet` for the `/vaadinServlet/*` & `/VAADIN` paths:

```
ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'springVaadinServlet' to [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
```

To co-exist with the dispatcher servlet and be able to serve requests also on "/*", Vaadin also registers a forwarding-controller for the `UI` paths. For example requests on `/MyUI` will be forwarded to `/vaadinServlet/MyUI` (see the [`VaadinServletConfiguration` sources](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/vaadin/spring/boot/internal/VaadinServletConfiguration.java) for more details).

Until now everything works fine and you should not have any issues. Just like you said, looking at the chrome dev-tools all the `js` files are there, so what's wrong? If you look closley at the requests made when you access your app, you'll notice that actually there are 2 requests for `pdf.worker.js` - the first one that is successful, and the one which gives you the 404:

[image: pdf.worker.js requests]

The `Initiator` column for the the call that fails, is actually [`pdf.js:2344`](https://github.com/radekpakula/pdf-viewr-addon/blob/vaadin8/pdfviewer-addon/src/main/java/pl/pdfviewer/pdf.js#L2344) and if you set a breakpoint you can actually see that `workerSrc=/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js`, value which is defined in [`pl.pdfviewer.client.ui.PdfViewer.java`](https://github.com/radekpakula/pdf-viewr-addon/blob/vaadin8/pdfviewer-addon/src/main/java/pl/pdfviewer/client/ui/VPdfViewer.java#L167). You may have to scroll horizontally a bit to be able to see the code, so I've formatted it below:

```
public native void loadResourcePdf(String fileName, VPdfViewer instance)/*-{
    var pdfviewer = instance.@pl.pdfviewer.client.ui.VPdfViewer::jsObject;
    pdfviewer.work = false;
    if ((pdfviewer.fileName == null || pdfviewer.fileName != fileName) && fileName != null) {
        $wnd.PDFJS.disableStream = true;
======> $wnd.PDFJS.workerSrc = 'APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js';
        $wnd.PDFJS.getDocument(fileName).then(function (pdf) {
            pdfviewer.pdfFile = pdf;
            pdfviewer.fileName = fileName;
            pdfviewer.pageCount = pdf.numPages;
            if (pdfviewer.pageNumber == 0 && pdf.numPages > 0) {
                pdfviewer.pageNumber = 1;
            }
            pdfviewer.showPdfPage(pdfviewer.pageNumber);
        });
    }

}-*/;
```

[image: js debug]

In a regular Vaadin environment, `/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js` would work out of the box, but we're now in a slightly altered one so we need some adjustments. Bottom line, we can use a similar approach to what Vaadin auto-configuration is doing, and redirect the  `/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js` request to `/vaadinServlet/APP/PUBLISHED/pdf.worker.js` and finally overcome the issue. For the sake of brevity, the redirect controller can be seen at the beginning of this post.

[image: working pdf]

Comment: Thanks, that works! I didn't take a look to the sources. I will create an issue for the addon creator.

Comment: @RedGato no problem.  Haven't had the time to investigate further, but I'm not sure whether he can do something. If it were possible to determine the path dynamically then we could have a fix, otherwise we still need to rely on this workaround. Nonetheless, if  you do open the issue, please make sure to add a link to this question for reference. Cheers